# Convert VM running on Linux hypervisor to OVF/VMDK

Tags: linux, vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter, conversion

I have a bunch of VMs on a Linux hypervisor (cloudsigma.com to be precised). I want to convert these to deploy to an ESX hypervisor (opsource cloud server), but need to create an ovf with the vmdk. I don't have access to the hypervisor of either service but opsource allow me to import ovf/vmdk so this is possible.

What tool can create an ovf (With vmdk) of a Windows OS? I am not sure if VCenter Converter would work as it requires access to the hypervisor, if I remember correctly. I am hoping for something like vhd2disk which will create a .vhd of the currently running, parent Windows OS on a system.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

vCenter converter can work on a powered on machine using the converter agent. Follow the P2V instructions. Sometimes you need to use a local administrator account instead of a domain administrator account to achieve the best results.